# How to include Nargs from argparse in my code without getting errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote cmd line interface to perform calculation on a number. If I enter using powershell the command:

```
python .\regex1.py *x 5 *y 6 *o mul
```

it prints:

```
In calc args
Something went wrong
```

However if i comment out Nargs it gives the expected results.

```
 entered thiscommand: python .\regex1.py *x 5 *y 6 *o mul
Got :mul
     30.0
```

Why is it so, why is Nargs creating this problem and how to solve it while keeping Nargs in our code? The code is below:

```
import argparse
import sys

def calc(args):
    print("In calc args")
    if str(args.o) == 'add':
        return args.x + args.y

    elif str(args.o) == 'mul':
        return args.x * args.y

    elif str(args.o) == 'sub':
        return args.x - args.y

    elif str(args.o) == 'div':
        return args.x / args.y

    else:
        return "Something went wrong"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog= "utility Calculator",
                                     usage= "To perform calculation on an integer",
                                     description="Thsi is arguments help",
                                     epilog="Hope your problem is resolved, if not contact me",
                                     prefix_chars="*",
                                     argument_default= 1.0,
                                     add_help= True,
                                     allow_abbrev= True
                                     )
    parser.add_argument('*x',
                        type=float,
                        action="store",
                        nargs=1,
                        help="Enter first number. This is a utility for calculation. Please contact me",
                        metavar= "  First Number"
                        )

    parser.add_argument('*y',
                        type=float,
                        action="store",
                        nargs=1,
                        help="Enter Second number. This is a utility for calculation. Please contact me",
                        metavar= "  Second Number"
                        )

    parser.add_argument('*o',
                        type=str,
                        # action="store"
                        nargs=1,
                        default= "add",
                        help="Enter the operand."
                             "*mul for multiplication"
                             "*add for addition"
                             "*div for division"
                             "*sub for subtraction",
                        metavar= "  Operand"
                        )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(str(args.o), args.x, args.y)
    sys.stdout.write(str(calc(args)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nargs` serves a different purpose and I'm not sure why you are trying to use it here since your arguments contain only one value.

When `nargs=1` your argument is actually a list of that single argument. If you remove the `nargs=1` you get the argument itself. And looking at your code, all `if` statements fail and that's why you get `Something went wrong`.

Referencing the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) where you can learn more about `nargs`:

`N` (an integer). `N` arguments from the command line will be gathered together into a list. For example:

```py
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2)
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs=1)
>>> parser.parse_args('c --foo a b'.split())
Namespace(bar=['c'], foo=['a', 'b'])
```

Note that `nargs=1` produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.